# JFrame displaying white when I place while loop

Tags: java, jpanel

I have added a while loop that will change between players as seen in the code below. Before I add this while loop it displays the grid, buttons, etc but when I add this loop the panel is just plain white. I have no idea why.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.omg.CORBA.PRIVATE_MEMBER;


public class Game 
{
    boolean p1;

    private int counterY1 = 515, counterY2 = 515, counterY3 = 515, counterY4 = 515;
    boolean playerTurn = true;
    boolean playerTurn2 = false;
    boolean moveLoop = true;

    public void moveC1Up()
    {
        counterY1 -= 51 * diceRoll();
    }
    public void moveC2Up()
    {
        counterY2 -= 51 * diceRoll();
    }
    public void moveC3Up()
    {
        counterY3 -= 51 * diceRoll();
    }
    public void moveC4Up()
    {
        counterY4 -= 51 * diceRoll();
    }

    public int diceRoll()
    {
        int randGen = (int)(Math.random()*1) + 1;
        System.out.print(randGen);
        return randGen; 
    }

    private JButton moveC1But, moveC2But, rollDiceButton;
    private JLabel amountRolledLabel;

    public Game()
    {


        JFrame window = new JFrame ("Main Game");
        final JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1))
        {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {   
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

                super.paintComponent(g2d);

                int width = getWidth() / 3;
                int height = getHeight() / 11;

                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    g.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, getHeight());
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                    g.drawLine(0, i * height, getWidth(), i * height);
                }

                g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                g.drawOval(220, counterY1, 40, 40);
                g.fillOval(220, counterY1, 40, 40);
                g.drawOval(300, counterY2, 40, 40);
                g.fillOval(300, counterY2, 40, 40);

                g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                g.drawOval(410, counterY3, 40, 40);
                g.fillOval(410, counterY3, 40, 40);
                g.drawOval(490, counterY4, 40, 40);
                g.fillOval(490, counterY4, 40, 40);
            }
        };

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.add(firstPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel rightSidePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10,1));
        moveC1But = new JButton("Move Counter 1");
        moveC2But = new JButton("Move Counter 2");
        rollDiceButton = new JButton("Roll Dice");
        rightSidePanel.add(moveC1But, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        rightSidePanel.add(moveC2But, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        rightSidePanel.add(rollDiceButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        mainPanel.add(rightSidePanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        window.setSize(700, 600);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setResizable(false);

        while(moveLoop  == true)
        {
            moveC1But.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
                {

                    diceRoll();
                    moveC1Up();
                    firstPanel.repaint();
                    System.out.print(diceRoll());
                    System.out.print("Test1");
                    playerTurn = false;
                    playerTurn2 = true;
                    moveLoop = false;

                }
            });

            moveC2But.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
                {

                    diceRoll();
                    moveC3Up();
                    firstPanel.repaint();
                    System.out.print(diceRoll());
                    System.out.print("Test1");
                    playerTurn = false;
                    playerTurn2 = true;
                    moveLoop = false;

                }
            });
        }

    }   

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new Game();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

EDIT:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.omg.CORBA.PRIVATE_MEMBER;


public class Game 
{
    boolean p1;

    private int counterY1 = 515, counterY2 = 515, counterY3 = 515, counterY4 = 515;
    boolean playerTurn = true;
    boolean playerTurn2 = false;
    boolean moveLoop = true;

    public void moveC1Up()
    {
        counterY1 -= 51 * diceRoll();
    }
    public void moveC2Up()
    {
        counterY2 -= 51 * diceRoll();
    }
    public void moveC3Up()
    {
        counterY3 -= 51 * diceRoll();
    }
    public void moveC4Up()
    {
        counterY4 -= 51 * diceRoll();
    }

    public int diceRoll()
    {
        int randGen = (int)(Math.random()*1) + 1;
        System.out.print(randGen);
        return randGen; 
    }

    private JButton moveC1But, moveC2But, rollDiceButton;
    private JLabel amountRolledLabel;

    public Game()
    {


        JFrame window = new JFrame ("Main Game");
        final JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1))
        {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {   
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

                super.paintComponent(g2d);

                int width = getWidth() / 3;
                int height = getHeight() / 11;

                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    g.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, getHeight());
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                    g.drawLine(0, i * height, getWidth(), i * height);
                }

                g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                g.drawOval(220, counterY1, 40, 40);
                g.fillOval(220, counterY1, 40, 40);
                g.drawOval(300, counterY2, 40, 40);
                g.fillOval(300, counterY2, 40, 40);

                g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                g.drawOval(410, counterY3, 40, 40);
                g.fillOval(410, counterY3, 40, 40);
                g.drawOval(490, counterY4, 40, 40);
                g.fillOval(490, counterY4, 40, 40);
            }
        };

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.add(firstPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel rightSidePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10,1));
        moveC1But = new JButton("Move Counter 1");
        moveC2But = new JButton("Move Counter 2");
        rollDiceButton = new JButton("Roll Dice");
        rightSidePanel.add(moveC1But, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        rightSidePanel.add(moveC2But, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        rightSidePanel.add(rollDiceButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        mainPanel.add(rightSidePanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        window.setSize(700, 600);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setResizable(false);

        if(playerTurn == true)
        {

            moveC1But.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
                {

                    diceRoll();
                    moveC1Up();
                    firstPanel.repaint();
                    System.out.print(diceRoll());
                    System.out.print("Test1");
                    playerTurn = false;
                    playerTurn2 = true;
                    moveLoop = false;

                }
            });

            moveC2But.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
                {

                    diceRoll();
                    moveC2Up();
                    firstPanel.repaint();
                    System.out.print(diceRoll());
                    System.out.print("Test1");
                    playerTurn = false;
                    playerTurn2 = true;
                    moveLoop = false;

                }
            });
        }else if (playerTurn2 == true)
        {
            moveC1But.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
                {

                    diceRoll();
                    moveC3Up();
                    firstPanel.repaint();
                    System.out.print(diceRoll());
                    System.out.print("Test1");
                    playerTurn = false;
                    playerTurn2 = true;
                    moveLoop = false;

                }
            });
            moveC2But.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
                {

                    diceRoll();
                    moveC4Up();
                    firstPanel.repaint();
                    System.out.print(diceRoll());
                    System.out.print("Test1");
                    playerTurn = false;
                    playerTurn2 = true;
                    moveLoop = false;

                }
            });
        }

        }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new Game();
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Why would you have `addActionListener()` declared in a while loop? Im sure this is causing problems

Answer (score 2):

In your current code the loop doesn't let the JFrame to call `repaint();` because it is never broken until the user clicks a button, which is impossible if the JFrame can't draw the components.

Here's how you should do your inputs instead.

```
package beaudoin.apps;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import sun.awt.RepaintArea;

public class Game {

    boolean p1;

    private int counterY1 = 515, counterY2 = 515, counterY3 = 515, counterY4 = 515;
    boolean playerTurn = true;
    boolean playerTurn2 = false;

    public void moveC1Up() {
        counterY1 -= 51 * diceRoll();
    }

    public void moveC2Up() {
        counterY2 -= 51 * diceRoll();
    }

    public void moveC3Up() {
        counterY3 -= 51 * diceRoll();
    }

    public void moveC4Up() {
        counterY4 -= 51 * diceRoll();
    }

    public int diceRoll() {
        int randGen = (int) (Math.random() * 1) + 1;
        System.out.print(randGen);
        return randGen;
    }

    private JButton moveC1But, moveC2But, rollDiceButton;
    private JLabel amountRolledLabel;

    public Game() {

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Main Game");
        final JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1)) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = -1729570833533906839L;

            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

                super.paintComponent(g2d);

                int width = getWidth() / 3;
                int height = getHeight() / 11;

                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    g.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, getHeight());
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                    g.drawLine(0, i * height, getWidth(), i * height);
                }

                g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                g.drawOval(220, counterY1, 40, 40);
                g.fillOval(220, counterY1, 40, 40);
                g.drawOval(300, counterY2, 40, 40);
                g.fillOval(300, counterY2, 40, 40);

                g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                g.drawOval(410, counterY3, 40, 40);
                g.fillOval(410, counterY3, 40, 40);
                g.drawOval(490, counterY4, 40, 40);
                g.fillOval(490, counterY4, 40, 40);
            }
        };

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.add(firstPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel rightSidePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10, 1));
        moveC1But = new JButton("Move Counter 1");
        moveC1But.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                diceRoll();
                moveC1Up();
                firstPanel.repaint();
                playerTurn = false;
                playerTurn2 = true;

            }
        });
        moveC2But = new JButton("Move Counter 2");
        moveC2But.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                diceRoll();
                moveC3Up();
                firstPanel.repaint();
                playerTurn = false;
                playerTurn2 = true;

            }
        });
        rollDiceButton = new JButton("Roll Dice");
        rightSidePanel.add(moveC1But, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        rightSidePanel.add(moveC2But, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        rightSidePanel.add(rollDiceButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        mainPanel.add(rightSidePanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        window.setSize(700, 600);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setResizable(false);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Game();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yours is a common problem: you've got a long-running bit of code that is running on the Swing event thread, completely tying it up. Since this thread is responsible for all of Swing drawing and user interaction, your GUI becomes essentially frozen until the long-running code finishes. Possible solutions include:

- Use a Swing Timer for your game loop, avoiding the use of `while (true)` on the Swing event thread.
- Use a background thread for a long-running bit of code. This can be conveniently be done with a SwingWorker.
- Do neither. Having a look at your code, I see no reason to have the `while (true)` loop in the first place. All it does is to add ActionListeners to JButtons multiple times and thus is completely worthless. So get rid of it and add the ActionListeners only **once**. For your code, this is your best option -- rethink your code so that it makes more sense.

---

**Edit**
You ask:

> Yes I see what the ifs are doing and have removed them. But basically I have two buttons, move counter 1 and move counter 2 each player has 2 counters, but only the two buttons. I want player 1 to start and hit which counter they would like to move, this then allows the second player to move their counter and visa versa.

The logic must be **inside** your ActionListener. For example:

```
  moveC1But.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        diceRoll();
        if (player1Turn) {
           // logic for player turn 1
        } else {
           // logic for player turn 2
        } 
     }
  });
```

Comment: See, I have removed the while and placed `if` statements as I need it to say `if player1Turn is true then move counter and turn it to false and player2Turn to true to allow the second player to move` however it does not turn to false and turn `playerturn2` to true, please view the edit

Comment: @HarryKitchener: get your addActionListener out of the if blocks. Those listeners must be added regardless of the state of any boolean. You need to write your program logic out on paper before committing it to code, to force yourself to think of what steps your code should be doing. Do this and your code will make more sense. Don't just type in code without planning first, trust me.

Comment: But surely if I remove them from the `if` then they can't be called? SO how would I alternate players? And I have done a small be of Pseudo code and Flow charting, but obviously not good enough.

Comment: @HarryKitchener: NO, that's not how ActionListeners work. Your if blocks are controlling the **creation** of the ActionListeners, not how they get called. They get called when the button is pressed, no more no less.

Comment: So how would I call it later on?

Comment: @HarryKitchener: ?? your ActionListeners will be called when the buttons are pressed. All logic about what happens when they are pressed should be **inside** the actionPerformed method. Do you see that you're if blocks are trying to control the **creation** of the listeners, not their behaviors?

Comment: Yes I see what the ifs are doing and have removed them. But basically I have two buttons, `move counter 1` and `move counter 2` each player has 2 counters, but only the two buttons. I want player 1 to start and hit which counter they would like to move, this then allows the second player to move their counter and visa versa.

Comment: I see, brilliant! But what is `playerturn`?

Comment: I meant, is that meant to be a boolean, or is it a new method you're creating. Sorry.

Comment: @HarryKitchener: please look at the syntax -- is that a method call? No. It's in an if evaluation clause, so it must be a.... what? Also, it there are only two players, then only one boolean variable is required. player1Turn is either true or false, and there's likely no need for player2Turn.

Comment: Please do not get sarcastic with the situation. I realise the mistake and I apologise, thanks for the help.

Comment: @HarryKitchener: I'm not getting sarcastic. Please don't misinterpret my posts. I'm trying to walk you through the logic, to make you think, for that's what you need to do in this situation. You need to look at a variable, and if it is in a boolean evaluation clause, it can only be one type of variable (unless it's part of a boolean expression, like `if (x == 2)`. So if you see `if (x)` then `x` **must** be a boolean. This is something that if you didn't know before, you *must* know now.

Comment: The two booleans are there as there are 4 counters. Counter 1 and 2 for P1 and Counter 1 and 2 for P2. Counter 1 for P1 will be true but for P2 it will be false, same with Counter 2.

Comment: Also, how would I switch the value of a boolean, I have tried :`playerTurn = !playerTurn;
                    playerTurn2 = !playerTurn2;` but it is not working.

Comment: 1) What is the underlying logic of this game as I am not familiar with it? Put this information as an edit to your question. 2) If you have code that is not working, show your latest code iteration as an edit to your original post and give the details on what is now wrong. Also note that `booleanVariable = !booleanVariable;` should work fine for toggling the state of a boolean variable.

Comment: I will update it tomorrow afternoon (GMT) as I must go now, thanks for the help so far

Comment: Ok, please view the latest update, that is the code for the movement of C1 and C3. However, for some reason it is not switching between the counters, possibly due to the booleans?

Comment: @HarryKitchener: in your latest code, I still see your mis-use of if blocks, I still don't see your use of if blocks *inside* of the ActionListeners where they belong.

Comment: It must not have updated or something. I have it working now anyway - I have placed the if statements inside of blocks and it is all working fine! Thanks.